# Spring Batch using different EntityManagerFactories causing org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-batch

Environment: JDK9.0.4, Spring Boot 2.0.2 with Spring Batch 4.0.1, using Postgres 9.5 and JPA via Hibernate.

My job uses JpaPagingItemReader and JpaItemWriter with a processor in between that updates values on the entity.

My issue is that my Batch job is throwing a org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException after processing the first item and attempting to read the next page (chunk/page size 1)

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect) : [com.my.entity#1315]
```

From debugging, it appears that Batch attempts to flush the JPA session in JPAPagingItemReader doReadPage(), but it's already been flushed during write() via (I think) another EMF that's somehow instantiated, and so Hibernate detects the version number has changed and throws the exception.

**Update**

I've found a couple of 5 year old forum posts/JIRAs that suggest that this is a limitation in Batch and a variety of workarounds. I'd be grateful for thoughts on whether I'm reading this right.

https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-1110

https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-1166

http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/batch/92792-jpapagingitemreader-stale-object-exception

If anyone can point towards any obvious pitfalls in this area I'd be grateful. I've read a fair amount of the Javadocs but struggling to understand the issue.

```
@Configuration
public class DBConfig {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);

        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource);
        em.setPackagesToScan("com.my.ents", "com.my.other.ends");

        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);

        return em;
    }

}



@Bean
@StepScope
public JpaPagingItemReader<ScrapeHistorySingle> getItemReader(
        @Value("#{jobParameters['council']}") String councilShortName,
        @Value("#{jobParameters['scrapeType']}") String scrapeTypeString) {

    if (councilShortName == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("councilShortName cannot be null");
    }

    if (scrapeTypeString == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("scrapeType cannot be null");
    }

    JpaPagingItemReader<ScrapeHistorySingle> itemReader = new JpaPagingItemReader<>();

    itemReader.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
```

...

```
@Bean
public JpaItemWriter<ScrapeHistorySingle> itemWriterScrapeHistorySingle() {

    JpaItemWriter<ScrapeHistorySingle> itemWriter = new JpaItemWriter<>();

    itemWriter.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);

    return itemWriter;
}


@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@Component
public class CustomBatchConfigurer extends DefaultBatchConfigurer {

    private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(CustomBatchConfigurer.class);

    @Autowired
    private ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor;

    @Autowired
    private JobRegistry jobRegistry;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Qualifier("transactionManager")
    @Autowired
    private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;
```

Comment: are you the only one using the server or concurrent requests are happening while this batch process is running? If it is the latter then an independent request might have updated a row.

Comment: @gagansingh Thank you for your comment; in this case I'm the only one using the server; it's a local containerized dev environment. I've updated the question as I think I've found some known limitations in Spring Batch that account for this.